# Create data visualizations using Express and get data from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, d3.js

I build a Node.js app that scrapes some informations from Internet and save these informations on a postgreSQL database.
Now I would like to create some visualizations using D3.js.
Usually I create visualizations using a `.csv` file, but now I would like to get data from my database.

I think to use `Express.js`. 
This is my code, it works but it take data from a `.csv` file, not from db.

**app.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

const start = async function() {
    console.log('\n(1) Connect to db');
    await postgreSQLlib.connect();

    console.log('\n(02) Create tables if they do not exist');
    await postgreSQLlib.createTables();

    console.log('\n(03) Check if table \'example\' is updated or not');
    if(!await utilFunc.isTableUpdated('example', 6308)) {
        console.log('\n  (04) Download data for coverages');
        await downloader.download();

        console.log('\n  (05) Elaborate data for example before to save on DB');
        await elaborate.elaborate();

        console.log('\n  (06) Saving data on db');
        await saveOnDb.save();
    }   

    console.log('\n(10) D3js visualizations');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 300)
    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Listening on PORT: ' + app.get('port'));
    });
    app.use('/',express.static('public/donut')) 

    // I can't disconnect from db if I have to show visualizations, am I right?
    console.log('\n(11) Disconnect');
    await postgreSQLlib.disconnect();
}

start()
.then(function(res) {
    console.log('Done');
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Donut</title>
       <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./donut.css" media="screen"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script src="./donut.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**donut.js**:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("./data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}
```

**data.csv**:

```
age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,4499890
14-17,2159981
18-24,3853788
25-44,14106543
45-64,8819342
≥65,612463
```

I try also:

```
const start = async function() {
    //...

    function onRequest(req, res) {
        if(req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/') {
            var client = new pg.Client(conString);
            client.connect();
            var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM example;');
            query.on('row', function(row, result) {
                result.addRow(row);
            });
            query.on('end', function(result) {
                res.status(200)
                res.json(result.rows);
                client.end();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
d3.csv("/", type, function(error, data) {
  if(error) { 
    throw error;
  }
  console.log('data:', data);
  ...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I wouldn't use a .csv file to store my data, but I want to use the db. 
How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to ask something more specific [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're not telling what went wrong. I see a weird CSV file.

I managed to get the donut using the CSV (after cleanup).

Comment: @ClemensTolboom I use [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) for the donut. It's only an example of visualization. In my work I will use other charts.

Comment: I reduced the json parsing to a single line of code if you're interesed in using the method In my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution require you to install two additional modules:

`npm install -save express-handlebars` & `npm install -save pg-promise`

After that in the `app.js` you could connect to your postgresql server and parse the data through handlebar helpers, here's all the code for that.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const pgp     = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

var app = express();

dbLoad();

function dbLoad() {

  var connect = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'postgres',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'YourPassword'
  };

  var db = pgp(connect); 

  db.query({
    text: 'SELECT * FROM table1',
    values: [],
    rowMode: 'array'
  })
  .then(data => {
    var arr = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var i = 0
      arr.push({
        age: d[i], 
        population: d[i + 1]
      })
      i++
    })

    pageLoad(arr); // Function call to load the page

  })
  .catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
  });

}

function pageLoad(data) {

  var hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: {
      sqlData: function () { return JSON.stringify(data); }
    }
  });

  app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

  app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {

      showTitle: true,
    });
  });

  app.listen(3000);

}
```

This assumes that you have the data on your server called table1 with the exact same data structure as your csv.

Then you should create a folder called *views* in the same folder as your `app.js` and create a file called `home.handlebars` (this is replacement for your `index.html`)

In this file you'll want to call your data like this {{sqlData}} and parse it.

**home.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart"></div>

</body>

<script>

var init = JSON.parse("{{sqlData}}".replace(/&quot;/g,'"').replace(/&lt;/,''))

chart(init);

function chart(data) {

  var width = 960,
      height = 500,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 10)
      .innerRadius(radius - 70);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

}

</script>
</html>
```

And that should be it.

**NOTE** I'm not an expert in node.js and there could be some serious security flaw with doing it this way if you're concerned about that, I'd suggest going though the [**express.js api**](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) and look through a proper way to get json object directly from the app.js without all the hacky string replacement I did in this solution.

**EDIT:**

Reduced the stringreplacement to a single line of code:

```
var init = JSON.parse("{{sqlData}}".replace(/&quot;/g,'"').replace(/&lt;/,''))
```

Comment: If I wanted to split the `home.handlebars` file from the script file?
I created a `donut.js` file saved in the views folder. So my `home.handlebars` file contains `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'>...<body></body><script src='/donut.js'></script></html>`. When I go to http://localhost:3000/, I get `Upload failed for <script> with source "http://localhost:3000/donut.js"`

Comment: @marielle Post a new question and you'd get better help from people more experienced with nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your d3 code into a function which gets called whenever you fetched your data **as json** by express.js call donut(json) like

**donut.js**:

```
function donut(json) {
  ...
  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(json))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

...
}
```

or use [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json) to fetch json from the server and pass in the URL like

```
...
d3.json(data_url, type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
...
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `json` in `donut()` function and `data_url` in `d3.json()`? I'm sure that to solve my problem, there is a very easy solution but I don't understand..

Comment: You saved the json into the database so you can fetch it through a database call using express code or when your database supports fetch it through a json url. btw I added link to my answer

Comment: I feel a bit stupid now. In my database I have a table not a json. I'm sure I can 'download' the data in a json format but is what you mean?How I build the url? I'm very confused

Comment: I assume you mean you saved the csv into your database. If so you can convert that into a data structure using https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#csvParse. If it is a database **table** I'm sure you can find a Express.js to fetch the data in a format usable for d3js right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The data is saved in database tables. I could certainly make a query to get the data and save it in a data structure (eg json). What I not able to do is organize the code. Consider that in my project I use multiple graphs that use different data. Where do I put the code related to the visualizationw? How do I organize everything? I would like to see a concrete example of what I would like to do. But I didn't find anything

Comment: Who is @beth? Weird

Comment: @beth you need to use the **function donut(json) {** call example then follow something in line with http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480 which you could split into two function which are called after you fetch their associated data.

Comment: @ClemensTolboom A colleague. We are working together on the same project.

Comment: @ClemensTolboom Can you please write a working example? I know how to build data viz. The problem is merge the front-end with the back-end, so merge Node.js code that do web scraping, code about PostgreSQL and code about data visualizations...